# String instance variable to JSON with JAXB annotation

Tags: java, json, jaxb

I have an object with a String instance variable in json format.

```
package json;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Test {

    private String json; // Contains a json String {"test": 1}

    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }
    public void setJson(String json) {
        this.json = json;
    }

}
```

When I marshal this object I get the following json:

```
{
   "json" : "{\"test\": 1}"
}
```

What I want is this:

```
{
    "json" : {
        "test" : 1
    }
}
```

Is there an annotation that allows to do that?

This is the sample code:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;

public class Main {

  public static void main (String [] args) throws JAXBException {

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);  

    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);  
    m.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
    m.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);


    Test t = new Test();
    t.setJson("{\"test\": 1}");

    m.marshal(t, System.out);  
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to find something equivalent in JAXB, but I couldn't. Jackson, for example, provides a `@JsonRawValue` annotation for this exact purpose. You can consider switching.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for this, this works fine, can you place this as an answer so that I can accept it?